Can proxy website or a VPN be copyright infringement?
If someone sets up an public web proxy server, which allows users to access the resources from a different website, and on the proxy home page, it writes that this is a proxy. In this case, according to the definition of copyright, copying copyrighted material, it should be copyright infringement.
In this case, is it a copyright infringement or not? If so, does every online proxy (such as hide.me) or VPN also have copyright infringement issue? As they are copying the material from the website and distribute to the user. What's the border of copyright infringement?

I'm not sure if the mere looks of the uri are definite enough to make one believe that it is indeed a proxy. Would you trust the implicit claim of a url www.definitely-not-a virus.ru/this-is-good-program.exe. And of course I also see serious security implications as it seems that your MITMS https traffic -- which in particular means that the end user  must assume they are talking to example_proxy_url.com and not to their_website.com. (While MITM it is common for proxies, they do so with "consent" of the user by trusting a special root certificate, whereas your cert may be globally trusted

Does it even matter? It doesn't seem likely an American court is likely to listen to Russian complaints given the state of geopolitics at the moment.

Yes, obviously.
You're copying copyrighted material without permission, which is basically the definition of copyright infringement.
There are of course exceptions, but admitting to copying is not one of them.

if this is the case, are all of the proxies online somehow copyright infringement? google online proxy

Are all shootings murder? Are all pictures of naked children child pornography? Are all punches assault? No, the answer varies from one case to the next, depending on the circumstances.

I’ve copied tons of copyrighted materials, music, videos, books, audiobooks without any copyright infringement. Most i paid for; Bach’s Complete organ music was free (recording by James Kibbie financed by the widow of a Bach fan).

This answer could be improved by saying how this is obvious, and how it is different from any other use of the internet.
